# What is the difference between node, vertex and point?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

Literature about graph databases talks about nodes, vertices and points. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the terms node, vertex and point. It is just a matter of the term that the author has decided to use.